# Laravel 5.1 Testing - getting row from database to complete test

Tags: php, mysql, testing, laravel-5.1

I am building a testing routine in Laravel 5.1 to run through the login process I have just created. I am wanting, as part of the testing, to test the password reset and change process.

The issue is that the password reset process generates and row in a table with a timestamp and uuid. The link remains valid for 1 hour for the reset to work.

The flow is:

1- Reset password by entering email address

2- System generates email with uuid link and sends to the user (currently it appears in the Laravel log).

3- User clicks on link from email, and if within one hour since it was generated, the user is presented with a password change screen. The link is also deleted from the table.

So now for my test code:

```
public function testSendPasswordLink()
{
    $this->visit('/login')
        ->click('Forgot Your Password?')
        ->seePageIs('/forgot-password')
        ->type('test@test.com','email')
        ->press('Send Password Reset Link')
        ->seePageIs('/login')
        ->see('A password reset link was sent to the email address supplied.')
        ->seeInDatabase('password_resets', ['email' => 'test@test.com']);
}
```

I would like to:

```
       ->getFromDatabase('password_resets', 'uuid')
       ->visit('/reset-password/'.$uuid)
       ->see(....
```

Is there a way of doing the above? I know how to `see in the table` but not how to `get from the table` in the test.

Alternatively is there a way to accomplish this via a different set of steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, insanity setting in... well, I am new at this so I will not execute myself as yet...! The answer was rather obvious (after sleeping on it!)

All I had to do is query the table and retrieve the token to perform the password reset test... below is the finished code:

1. Add Eloquent to the test php file

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
2. Below is the complete function:

   public function testChangePassword()

   ```
   $this->visit('/login')
       ->click('Forgot Your Password?')
       ->seePageIs('/forgot-password')
       ->type('test@test.com','email')
       ->press('Send Password Reset Link')
       ->seePageIs('/login')
       ->see('A password reset link was sent to the email address supplied.')
       ->seeInDatabase('password_resets', ['email' => 'test@test.com']);

   $uuid = DB::table('password_resets')
       ->where('email', '=', 'test@test.com')
       ->value('token');

   $this->visit('/reset-password/' . $uuid)
       ->type('bbbbbbbb','password')
       ->type('bbbbbbbb','password_confirmation')
       ->press('Change Password')
       ->see('Your password was reset.')
       ->seePageIs('/login')
       ->type('test@test.com','email')
       ->type('bbbbbbbb','password')
       ->press('Sign In')
       ->seePageIs('/welcome')
       ->click('Logout')
       ->seePageIs('/login');

   // Change password back
   $this->visit('/login')
       ->click('Forgot Your Password?')
       ->seePageIs('/forgot-password')
       ->type('test@test.com','email')
       ->press('Send Password Reset Link')
       ->seePageIs('/login')
       ->see('A password reset link was sent to the email address supplied.')
       ->seeInDatabase('password_resets', ['email' => 'test@test.com']);

   $uuid = DB::table('password_resets')
       ->where('email', '=', 'test@test.com')
       ->value('token');

   $this->visit('/reset-password/' . $uuid)
       ->type('abcd1234','password')
       ->type('abcd1234','password_confirmation')
       ->press('Change Password')
       ->see('Your password was reset.')
       ->seePageIs('/login')
       ->type('test@test.com','email')
       ->type('abcd1234','password')
       ->press('Sign In')
       ->seePageIs('/welcome')
       ->click('Logout')
       ->seePageIs('/login');
   ```

By the way, I cannot seem to format the code with the {} brackets, so apologies.